# Create and configure a Windows taskbar toolbar via a script

Tags: windows, powershell, taskbar, toolbar

When I right-click a Windows taskbar toolbar, I can toggle some options such as *Show Text*, *Show Title* and *Lock the Taskbar*. I can also reorder the icons on the toolbar and set it's position.

How can I do the following via a script?

- create a new taskbar toolbar
- set the toolbar position
- set the order of the icons
- toggle *Show Text*
- toggle *Show Title*
- lock the toolbar

Comment: All can be done using powershell since powershell can use C# library. Search  the internet for Poweshell solutions.

Comment: I suspect that when you change settings a desktop.ini file is created inside the toolbar with attribute hidden. Otherwise it is set through the registry. My knowledge is not sufficient enough to answer this, which is why I added a comment instead. It may help others write a solution.

Comment: Thanks @SNash but I'd already searched. Seems [it's not so simple](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e89059d0-a60d-4cb3-aa58-875cb8f90e10/enablingshowing-the-links-toolbar-on-the-windows-taskbar-via-powershell?forum=ITCG)...

Comment: Yeah @LPChip I'd looked for a desktop.ini, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the settings can only be altered by the user, this was a concious design decision by Microsoft. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/420085/how-can-i-pin-a-program-to-the-windows-7-taskbar-with-parameters) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx) for some reasons why. If the user runs the script their taskbar could be adjusted. See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/09/01/how-can-i-add-a-shortcut-to-the-quick-launch-tray.aspx) for an example.